# Removing folders with "bad" names on GitHub

Tags: github, directory

I did not realize that certain characters were not allowed for folder names on github and named a couple of folders with the character ":". I cannot figure out how to rename/delete these folders. I don't care about the data inside, I can just reupload.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The colon character is fine.  Some operating systems can't handle that character in path names (e.g., Windows), but Git and GitHub should have no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks bk, I feel a bit better now. However most of my team will be using windows (myself included). For all directories with a colon in the name, they wont be able to pull them correct? If so, I need to figure out how to change.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Git is capable of handling arbitrary byte sequences in file names because it's designed for Unix systems.  That means any character except forward slash or NUL can appear in a path component, including characters such as 0xfe and 0xff, which are not valid UTF-8.  Colons are one of those permitted characters.

GitHub also does not have a problem with arbitrary bytes.  However, if the path isn't valid UTF-8, it might not be rendered properly in the web interface, although it should still be supported via operations with Git.

However, there are some operating systems which are less capable.  For example, Windows excludes many common punctuation characters from permissible file names.  As a result, you may wish to be kind to users of those operating systems and not use file names that cause problems there.

Since you're on Windows, you'll have some trouble checking out the repository.  The best thing to do is clone the repository on a Linux system or under Windows Subsystem for Linux and then rename the files or directories with `git mv`, then commit and push.  macOS should also be able to handle colons in path names, although it requires that the path names be valid UTF-8.